# Professional way to create a multi-lingual website?

Tags: localization, internationalization

I am seeing many sites on the web that suggest a language choice -  usually two or three languages and it changes the entire site into the selected language.

- I want to know how to do it professionally?
- Is there any plugin that makes life easier?
- can google-translate be molded to make this happen?
- I want to change the language of my site to 7-languages? How can this be done?
- my site uses HTML,css,JQuery,AJAX and PHP, MySQL...so kindly guide me as such.
- what I am currently doing is loading a different page (which has been written in that language) when a user click on any language.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="page_lang1">lang 1</a><br/>
<a href="page_lang2">lang 2</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155706/what-are-good-tools-frameworks-for-i18n-of-a-php-codebase

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Multi-regional and multilingual sites**

yes you can do that with the help of google translate and as far as i know this is a easier approach than the others and saves a lot of time.

you are probably looking  for this,go though the link:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en

Comment: go through the link i provided

Answer (score 1):

use language files to store your i18n like this:

en.php

```
$lang['hello'] = 'hello';
```

fr.php

```
$lang['hello'] = 'bonjour';
```

then in your code, use something like this instead of directly writing the word:

```
echo lang('hello');
```

with the function:

```
function lang($key){
  return $lang[$key];
}
```

And then load en.php if language is set to en, fr for fr, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by many ways. It depends on how you would like to do it.

In PHP if you use a specific modern framework I'm sure you would find something related.

In jQuery you can also find some [plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-translator-plugins/) that would do the job.

But as for 7 languages, I can expect that you might have rtl languages, such as Arabic or Hebrew, in this case you don't need only a translation way, but you also need to modify your css.

Hope this helps.