# Are there any library for i18n on plain php (without any framework)?

Tags: php, internationalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you build a multi-language web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562/how-do-you-build-a-multi-language-web-site)

I inherited some code which is just plain php where I have to do some changes.
Because the changes are rather small and the biggest request is support for multi-language, I chosen to keep existing code instead of rewriting it, but I need an i18n library for plain php.

Are there any default library that is used with plain php? I really don't know, a link to usage/download will be really helpful.

**Update 1:**

It would be nice if you can point me to some console-like tool that helps me build a file with all strings that should be translated, instead of doing it by hand (in CakePHP is every instance between `__()` function).

Comment: @hakre: Nope, the answer is completely different from what I'm requesting and here we are talking about php, while there we are talking about java.

Comment: I'd say reading helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41379/367456

Comment: @hakre: Thanks i didn't notice that, well that answer is great, however I don't know if the question **is** actually a duplicate of this because I think it's only a case that there is a php answer there.

Comment: The duplicate suggestion is my 2 cents, another of my 2 cents is: gettext works very well and it is fast. it works pretty stand-alone and if you learn about it, it's for other computer languages available, too and a toolchain exists as well as fallback libraries. So it can not get much easier. For your update: Poedit does that `_()` parsing for you. And more tools exist, that's just one/two.

Comment: @hakre: Thanks a lot, this really helped me. By the way, I think that keeping this question is a good idea for people looking specifically for a php i18n lib, the other is a bit generic and this could help search enginges. Anyway thanks to everyone, this completely solved my issue.

Comment: Don't worry, marking a question as a (possible) duplicate does not delete it.

Comment: @hakre: This is by no means a duplicate of the other question. While the answers might be similar (gettext), the *question* itself is totally different (it's about PHP, not Java) and that's what counts.

Comment: I can't believe this has been voted as exact duplicate, we are talking about 2 completely different language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php)(since php 5.3) and [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)(since forever)

From php intl extension docs page:

> Internationalization extension (further is referred as Intl) is a
>   wrapper for [ICU](http://www.icu-project.org/) library, enabling PHP programmers to perform
>   [UCA](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/)-conformant collation and date/time/number/currency formatting
>   in their scripts.

From gettext docs page:

> This package offers to programmers, translators and even users, a well
>   integrated set of tools and documentation. Specifically, the GNU
>   gettext utilities are a set of tools that provides a framework within
>   which other free packages may produce multi-lingual messages.

Comment: Why should I choose one or another? Also, are there any helpful console command (like cake) that build a locales file with all instances of my should-be-translated strings?

Comment: You should choose both not one or another. Also there are helpful console commands if you install gettext on your computer. yes yes. but well, reading helps. :)

Comment: They are for different things. Intl - for output of dates/currency/transliteration/formatting numbers in a localized way. gettext is for translation.

Comment: @kgb: Thanks, that's important! I should use both so.

Answer (score 2):

[gettext](http://php.net/gettext) is the default PHP i18n extension using the very ubiquitous gettext system.