# localization in JSP using JSTL and key/values from the database

Tags: java, database, jstl

I am building a web application with JSP and Java Servlet. Currently I am using JSTL fmt for the internationalization using a property file (messages.properties). But my costumer wants to be able to update text live so I need to move keys/value from the property file to the database. The problem is I don't know how I can read text from the database into for exemple
`<fmt:message>` tag in the JSP file.

Any help is very welcome, thanks

//Momo

Comment: Database queries are heavyweight; if for every caption in your web page you must do a query it will be very slow. I advice a mechanism for reloading the internationalization bundle when desired.

Comment: Do you already have database access set up? You could store names and descriptions of objects with a locale oder language key in your database and let your servlet have determine the current locale.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @SJuan76 it is true that the application will be very slow with this solution. Do you have any suggestion on how to reload the internationalization bundle when desired?

Comment: @Paujo yes I have alreaday database access setup and can retrieve key/value pair. The problem is to pass them to the JSP file.

Comment: Either if you read it from a file or from DB, you must cache it in a mpa (I have not used `fmt`, I usually use `ResourceBundle` which already does it). Provide a method to reload that map from source again.

Comment: How do you pass data from Servlet to JSP file at the moment? `HttpServletRequest.setAttribute("attribute", "value")` should work.

Comment: Ok, I will do that @SJuan76 . Yes I am using HttpServletRequest.setAttribute("attribute", "value") to pass data to the JSP

Answer (score 1):

`<fmt:message>` can make use of a `LocalizationContext` which, in turn, makes use of a `ResourceBundle`. So, really, you should focus on how to create a `ResourceBundle` that meets your needs. If you absolutely have to use a database, perhaps someone's already created a `ResourceBundle` implementation to handle that. One thing to make sure you investigate, as long as you're using at least Java 6, is `ResourceBundle.Control`. It may turn out that you can keep using property files but customize the caching behavior.

Comment: Yes I'am using Java 6. Using property files with a caching behavior sounds like the best solution. I will investigate the approche. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not with `fmt`. You either write your own tag or you change the code of `fmt`.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a solution? Instead of reading from the database för every key/value pair I read them into a map and refresh every knight.
[Database backed i18n for java web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295/database-backed-i18n-for-java-web-app)