# Multiple language support in Spring project without using multiple message_language.properties files

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to add different languages support in my Spring Web-MVC application without adding message_language.properties file for each language.
But I found message_language.properties file solution everywhere.
I searched deeply but I haven't got any solution for it.
please suggest me any solution....

Comment: one properties file per language is the java standard.  consider not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what are the reasons why you search for a different solution. Perhaps not what you want, but many projects that require dynamic language addition use database backed resource bundles (technically speaking its the solution without the properties file, but essentially the approach is the same).

If this is what you want you can check out the blog http://www.webreference.com/programming/Globalize-Web-Applications15_Java_ResourceBundles/index.html.

The following stackoverflow could be helpful as well
[Database backed i18n for java web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295/database-backed-i18n-for-java-web-app)